# How To Replace SubString Of JSon String With Required Substring

Tags: c#, regex, json, string, substring

Following string contains JSon parsed string.

```
      string myJSonString="{ \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"54f6b062036de221c00f5540\" }, \"account\" : \"Acc1\", \"accuser\" : \"\", \"curstatus\" : \"booked\" }";

      string oldString=" { \"$oid\" :";
      string newString="";
```

I am using below code for replacing the substring using regex but it doesn't work;

```
    string   result = Regex.Replace(myJSonString, oldString, newString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Second Replace

```
    string oldStrin="}, \"account\"";
   string newString=", \"account\"";
  string   finalResult = Regex.Replace(result , oldString2, newString2, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This code doesn't work for me;

Comment: can you give example for this

Comment: @JamesThorpe: `{` can be indeed a special character only if it is the start of a quantifier *(followed by `m,n}` or `n}`)*. Most of the time you don't need to escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really as simple as in your example, I would use a regular string replacement, which I find much easier to understand:

```
string myJSonString="{ \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"54f6b062036de221c00f5540\" }, \"account\" : \"Acc1\", \"accuser\" : \"\", \"curstatus\" : \"booked\" }";

string result = myJSonString.Replace(" { \"$oid\" :", "").Replace("}, \"account\"", ", \"account\"");

//{ "_id" : "54f6b062036de221c00f5540" , "account" : "Acc1", "accuser" : "", "curstatus" : "booked" }
```

Comment: Yes this approach came to mind after I wrote my answer too - note that your second replace isn't correct at the moment, it should be replacing with `, "account"` - ie just removing the `}`

Comment: @EagleBeak Thanks it works for me i didn't know that it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your version probably isn't working due to the fact that `$` is a special character in regular expressions - it is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), denoting the end of a line or the end of a string, so it needs to be escaped with a `\`.

Having said that, rather than replacing the section before and after the ID with nothing, instead we can construct a single regex to find the entire section and replace it with just the inner ID:

```
string pattern = "{ \"\\$oid\" : (\"[a-z0-9]+\") }";

string myJSonString = "{ \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"54f6b062036de221c00f5540\" }, \"account\" : \"Acc1\", \"accuser\" : \"\", \"curstatus\" : \"booked\" }";

string finalResult = Regex.Replace(myJSonString, pattern, "$1");
```

Comment: Thanks dear but there is another issue that your pattern remove braces from \"54f6b062036de221c00f5540\" and gives "54f6b062036de221c00f5540" which creates problem for me

Comment: @SyedMuhammadMubashir When you say braces, I think you mean quotes?  I've updated the answer so that the quotes are part of the capture group and will be in the replacement now.

Comment: sorry I meant forward slash not the braces

Comment: Note that your original string _does not contain slashes_.  They are escaping the following quotes.  I suspect the way you're inspecting the replaced value means you no longer see them (nor should you).  Inspect the original string in the same fashion and you'll see it doesn't have any either.

Comment: they represent the BSon Document converted to a valid JSon String, and the slashes are added to the string on conversion.